# How to extract OpenGL Polygon Rasterization?

Tags: opengl, raster

I have a triangle mesh that I am rendering in OpenGL. I need to get a mapping from each pixel in the resulting view to the index of the polygon associated with it. Is there an easy way to do that?

If it is possible do that easily, what would be a reasonable datatype for storing it?

Answer (score 3):

Draw into a framebuffer with an integer texture backing it.  You can use `gl_PrimitiveID` as the value in the fragment shader to write as output.  This will give you a map from pixel to the primitive index.

Comment: Note that `gl_PrimitiveID` is *not unique* across render commands. It gets reset at the beginning of each draw.

Comment: @DietrichEpp So if I understand correctly, I would bind a new texture with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, framebuffer.textures[0]); glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, gl_PrimitiveID);`? And then read it back with: `glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT)`

Comment: Also, what would the result of that be for pixels that do not have any primitives?

Comment: @paleon12: Drawing won't affect pixels that don't have any primitives, they would retain whatever value they had before the draw call.